# C# putting datagridview date show in a datetimepicker

Tags: c#, .net

```
private void dgw_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
       DataGridViewRow dr = dgw.SelectedRows[0];
       TextBox1.Text = dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
       cmdproduct.Text = dr.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
       txtqty.Text = dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
       txtrate.Text = dr.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
       //txtstockdate.Text = dr.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
       // txtstockdate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dr.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the question, for we do not know what you would like us to answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
 DateTime stockDate;
 if (DateTime.TryParse(dr.Cells[4].Value.ToString(), out stockDate))
 {
     dateTimePicker1.Value = stockDate;
 }
```